# Crashing when reading a file through JNI but successful when running just the C element of code

Tags: java, c, file, input, java-native-interface

i have a program that has java code and then C code that uses a JNI interface, the task that i am trying to acomplish is to replace some of the java files with C source files and then use a JNI to achieve the same program but with C file included. Therefore i know there is no issue with the Java code. In a source file i have a function called readMap() which is causing the issue.

I have managed to narrow down the issue to the fact that the C code for some reason will not read the map, the following if statement is executed when the function is called through the JNI:

```
if(in = fopen("../maps/example_map.txt", "r") == NULL)
        {
           printf("Error opening file\n");
           exit(-1);
        }
```

However if i run just the C code from a main() in MainTest.c the function will read in the map fine and all of the C code will work, therefore i rules out the possibility of the class path being wrong.

I have also narrowed out the JNI itself as other functions will be able to be called and return the desired result when they are called but if readMap() is called then it will not work.

Basically i was wondering if anyone else has had a similar problem with this and what their fix was or if anyone has any ideas about what it could be?

Comment: You need to learn about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) because the expression `in = fopen(...) == NULL` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Are you sure the working directory is the same in both cases? Try using an absolute path.

Comment: A perfect example of *why* `if(in = fopen("../maps/example_map.txt", "r") == NULL)` is *bad* code.  Do it in at least two lines:  `FILE *in = fopen(...); if ( in == NULL )...` and there's *no* way to make that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it wasn't working in case anyone else was has this issue, the problem was with the class path, the class path was relative and so it was from where the C file was, however it need to be from where the main java file was as that is where the code was being executed.

Down to me keeping Java code in a file with two files one for maps and another for jni (C code), therefore the path that made the C work was "../maps/example_map.txt" and for the java code needed to be "maps/example_map.txt".

Thought id leave it up incase anyone else ran into this problem.